# How did Amy survive the crack in her wall?

Tags: doctor-who

How did Amy Pond survive without being consumed by the crack on her wall, given that the same crack consumed her parents?

I haven’t seen season 6 yet, so no spoilers please.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit much to ask for no spoilers for a series that aired more than three years ago.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: is it though? In the age of Netflix?

Answer (score 8):

Without spoiling Series 6 all I can really tell you is that it was not a coincidence that Amy was the one who's wall was cracking, so she has a special relationship with them.

> The cracks are actually the universe crack *around her*, as she was used as the focal point for the explosion.

There are a couple of hints in Season 5 that Amy is somehow special, in particular:

- Throughout the season, it's revealed that most of Amy's family has "mysteriously disappeared" except herself.
- In "Flesh and Stone", The Doctor reveals that the explosion occurs at exactly the same time as Amy's wedding day

Ultimately, we find out that there was a bigger plan at work:

> The long-term plan, drawn up by The Silence, is to contrive to create a part-Time Lord capable of killing The Doctor. By ensuring that she and Rory spent their wedding night on the TARDIS, and thus their daughter was conceived while in the Time Vortex, they got what they were after. (Every indication we has is that The Silence were the ones that caused the TARDIS to explode, but we're not explicitly told why. The only reasonable assumption I can come up with is that it was part of this longer term plan.)

Comment: so I ll get to know why Amy was specifically not consumed and how she was influenced by the time field in the next season ?

Comment: "how" might be asking a bit much from Doctor Who... but yes, it will make more sense when you see what else makes her special.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: I’ve just re-watched most of season 6, and I don’t recall a trap that caused the Tardis explosion, nor Amy being described as the centre of the cracks. Which episode was that in?

Comment: Paul - It wasn't a single episode but rather the overall idea that The Silence were directing events such that River Song would be born, combined with the fact that Amy and her wedding day and her life in general were central to the events that led up to that. Also, there were "hints" in Season 5 that I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amy might not be consumed by the crack cause there was no one in it but when his parents were there some one was in it i wont say who cause spoilers.